# For loop with variable upper bound

Tags: variables, for-loop, wolfram-mathematica

I'd like to write a for loop with a variable upper limit in Mathematica 9. So, instead of

```
  j = 0;
  For[n = 1, n <= 3, n++, j = j + n];
  j
  (*6*)
```

I'd like to do

```
  N = 3;
  j = 0;
  For[n = 1, n <= N, n++, j = j + n];
  j
  n
  (*
  0
  1
  *)
```

. But, as shown, this does not give the right result at all; it would appear from the value of `n` that the body of the loop was not evaluated at all.

I've looked through the Mathematica docs both on for loops and and on loops and control structures more generally (and also done some DuckDuckGo searches), but there's still something fundamental I'm missing. What is it?

For completeness, I should note that my ultimate goal is to put this in a function:

```
foo[N] =
 Module[{j = 0},
   For[n = 1, n <= N, n++, j = j + n;];
   j]
foo[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows several common new user's problems. For example:

- `N` is a reserved word
- You shouldn't start your identifiers with Upper Case letters
- The function `foo[]` should be defined with SetDelayed (`:=`) and not
  with Set (`=`)
- You need to use patterns (`_`) in the function definition arguments
- `For[]`loops, and iterations in general should be avoided in
  Mathematica

I think you could carefully read all the answers to [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users) to get a better grip on Mathematica.

Anyway, your code may be rewritten as

```
foo[k_] := Module[{j = 0}, For[n = 1, n <= k, n++, j = j + n]; j]
foo[3]
(*6*)
```

But this is horrible Mathematica coding.
The following are much better ways in Mathematica:

```
foo[j_ , k_] := Fold[Plus, j, Range@k]
foo[j_ , k_] := j + Total@Range@k
foo[j_ , k_] := j + Tr@Range@k
```

Comment: The fact that N is reserved was my most immediate problem. Thanks for pointing the rest out, though, and thanks especially for pointing me to the newbie-problems question: it's going to take me a while to digest that, but it looks really helpful. Also, do you know off-hand of a good comparison of Mathematica to Scheme or maybe Haskell? Pretending it's Matlab clearly doesn't work very well, but pretending it's a Lisp doesn't always work, either.

Comment: @ChristopherWhite Don't let the syntactic sugar misguide you. Mathematica is a functional, term rewriting language. There are a few constructs that carry side effects only to ease some complicated operations, but those can generally be avoided. You shouldn't use loops in Mathematica, except for **really** exceptional situations.